# Wrap csv content in <pre> tag in controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, iframe

I need to return a csv file content from my controller method and display it inside iframe by src url. The best way to do it is just to use text/plain as ContentType, but in this case I have no control over the file content styling on the client side (it makes word wrap by default, which I do not expect to see for csv file).

So I managed to wrap csv content in  tag passing my own styles on the server side, and return it as text/html file. Sometimes it works, sometimes I get decoding error. How it can be fixed? Or there is another solution exists?

Comment: *"I get decoding error"* - Can you be more specific? What's the exact error? What's giving you the error?

Comment: Sure, net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED.
I see it in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Don't forget to add:

`Response.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", Encoding.UTF8.ToString());`

to avoid issues with encoding